Q&A: Macro that hides rows in worksheets based on selecting a cell from an input box
Here is the link of my previous question related to hiding columns based on selecting a cell from an input box:
How to Correct a macro that hides columns in worksheets based on selecting a cell from an input box
The question answered perfectly by (tailer), who provide the correct macro.
Today I modify the code to hide the rows (see related paragraph below).

The macro code to hides rows in worksheets based on selecting a cell from an input box:
Sub HideRowsAllVisibleUnprotSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim c As Range, vMch
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "Choose the cell you want to hide rows in all visible unprotected sheets in this workbook, based on the value of that cell."
    On Error Resume Next
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Select one cell :", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If InputRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' cancel InputBox
    If InputRng.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then ' select multiple cells
        MsgBox "Please selecte ONE cell."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Len(InputRng.Value) = 0 Then ' blank cell
        MsgBox "Because the selected cell is empty, the macro was not executed."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If the sheet is hidden or protected go to next sheet
        If ws.Visible And (Not ws.ProtectContents) Then
            For Each c In ws.UsedRange.rows ' loop through rows
                vMch = Application.Match(InputRng.Value, c, 0) ' search target value
                If Not IsError(vMch) Then ' found
                    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

